# How to show multiple thumbs for file multiple object in fields_form in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

i have a a multiple image selector in fields_form in prestashop using HelperForm.

```
'EN' => [
                'type' => 'file',
                'multiple' => true,
                'max_files' => 8,
                'label' => $this->l('Images (EN)'),
                'name' => 'EN'
            ]
```

Now i'am asking how can i display a thumb of all images selected when i choose to edit object.

there is an option in HelperForm that allow me to show one thumb.

```
'EN' => [
                'type' => 'file',
                'label' => $this->l('EN'),
                'name' => 'EN',
                'display_image' => true,
                'image' => $image_en_start_url ? $image_en_start_url : false
            ],
```

So how can i diplay multiple thumbs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another sort to show all thumnails of a multiple file field whene we choose to edit the object.

The parametre image accepte a string (thumbnail)

```
<img src="/bb_dev/img/tmp/operation_133-1.jpg?time=1482335015" alt="" class="imgm img-thumbnail" />
```

So whene can create one string which containe all thumbs.

```
$image_en_start = $dir . '' . $obj->id . '/FR/' . $obj->id . '-0.jpg';
    $image_en_start_url = ImageManager::thumbnail($image_en_start, $this->table . '_' . (int) $obj->id . '-0.' . $this->imageType, 50, $this->imageType, true, true);
    $image_en_coupon = $dir . '' . $obj->id . '/FR/' . $obj->id . '-1.jpg';
    $image_en_coupon_url = ImageManager::thumbnail($image_en_coupon, $this->table . '_' . (int) $obj->id . '-1.' . $this->imageType, 50, $this->imageType, true, true);
    $image_en_start_url .=$image_en_coupon_url;
```

And passe it as image parametre. Now we have two thumbs in one string (that allow us to preview two images)

```
'FR' => [
                'type' => 'file',
                'multiple' => true,
                'max_files' => 8,
                'label' => $this->l('Images (FR)'),
                'name' => 'FR',
                'display_image' => true,
                'image' => $image_en_start_url ? $image_en_start_url : false
            ],
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. When use `display_image` parameter form only display first of all selected images. That's the way it is developed. If you want to change this behavior you must do your own customization of uploader TPLs at folder `admin_folder\themes\default\template\helpers\uploader`

Good luck.